# Congifure Stripe in a Rails Engine with .env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, stripe-payments, rails-engines

I'm having trouble setting up stripe in a Rails::Engine, This is kinda a two-fold question as the 2nd one pertains to loading the envs, which is acting funny but will get to that.

Goal here is to break out a subscription process from a big Rails application.

**update** 
So as I was typing this all out I actually got it to work. Posted answer below. Feel free to comment and provided a better way to do this.

**1st question STRIPE CONFIG**

question how to set up stripe in a rails engine. Separate from Parent Engine or Rails app. I have tried a few things.

**2nd question loading envs**

.envs are not being loaded when running a local server for the dummy app yet are being loaded in the specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stripe Config**

```
#/:engine_name/engine.rb
require "dotenv-rails"

module :engine_name
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace :engine_name

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
    end

    #load envs
    Dotenv::Railtie.load

    initializer "config.stripe" do |app|
      config.stripe = {
        :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
        :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
      }

      Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    end
  end
end
```

**Loading .env**

So above the initializer "config.stripe" the block is passed the parent Rails app. Which when running the dummy app locally or the engine in tests thats the dummy app. This leads to the Dummy app being the root location. The confusing part was for tests the .env was also loaded when in the Engine root path, but this would not load for the engine.

So your .env must go in the dummy apps root. Though loaded by the Engine not the Rails::app. Though The Engine will acquire all Parent Apps ENV's. It's kinda confusing but makes sense in the end.